# Reg Exp For Ignoring White Space In Date Format

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to create reg_exp for matching the given date string. In that date string following format is possible

```
01.12.1990
01. 12. 1990
```

I created the reg_exp for the first format (i.e) without space between day, month, year. But its not working for the second format too. How can i make the reg_exp which should support both and get the date?

My reg_exp is below,

```
$dateString = "01.12.1990";
preg_match("/^(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1]).(0[1-9]|1[0-2]).[0-9]{4}$/",$dateString))
```

Comment: Why not first remove all the spaces from input and then do matching.

Comment: your regex would be `^(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])\.\s*(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\.\s*[0-9]{4}$` http://regex101.com/r/xP2nY1/1

Comment: i am trying getting that data by matching only. before that i wont have that data.

Comment: don't check the dates using regex.

Comment: Avinash your reg_exp works. Thanks and y i should not check date using regex?

Comment: Because checking date using regex is error prone.

Comment: Replace whitespaces away before parsing `s/\s+//`

Comment: `$dateString = "01. 12. 1990"; $dateString = str_replace(' ', '', $dateString);`

Comment: Do you want to check if the date is valid or grab the date values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use \s 
Read More about [Escape](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php)

```
$dateString = "01 . 12 . 1990";
preg_match_all("/^(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])\s*.\s*(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\s*.\s*[0-9]{4}$/is",$dateString,$res);
print_r($res);
```

Comment: it's optional, maybe you have more spaces between dots or no space.

Comment: Yes you're right, it was my mistake, i have it edited.

Comment: You must escape the dot.

Comment: I think it's not necessary! this format can accept different date spliter like: (,) comma and (-) dash

Comment: It matches a string with 10 digit.

Answer (score 0):

The following and using [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) will echo:

```
01.12.1990
Match
```

```
<?php
$dateString = "01. 12. 1990"; 
$dateString = str_replace(' ', '', $dateString);

echo $dateString;

if( preg_match("/^(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1]).(0[1-9]|1[0-2]).[0-9]{4}$/",$dateString)) {
echo "<br>";
echo "Match";
}

else{
echo "<br>";
echo "No match";
}
```

If using `$dateString = "01. 12. 1990x";` with a letter inside will echo

```
01.12.1990x
No match
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do not you work with dates by the **strftime**?
http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)